# Kubernetes ResourceQuota and Autoscale

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-vm-scale-set, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I have an azure Kubernetes cluster which include 2 types of nodepools inside it. Let's assume **vm1 has 2vcpu & 8GB ram** and **vm2 has 8vcpu & 32GB ram**. Also, I have fully functional set of applications which runs on those two nodepools by using **nodeSelector/agentpool** *(some are defined to run on nodepool 1 and other on nodepool 2)*. Both the nodepools are set up for vm level autoscale as minimun nodepool as 1 and it can extend upto 3. My applications are working perfectly with horizontal pod autoscaling and vm *(nodepool)* level scalling with current setup. Now I want to set up new cluster include two namespaces with ResourceQuota defined. 
My problem is let's say we defined 2 namespaces as QA and Dev and assign some ResourceQuota as below for example,

```
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: namespace-quota-allocation
  namespace: myNamespace
spec:
  hard:
    requests.cpu: "1"
    requests.memory: 2Gi
    limits.cpu: "2"
    limits.memory: 2.5Gi
```

Then how the VM level scale going to happen and how can i test that? can someone explain please.

**My current architecture is like this,**
[image]

**And I want something like this with vm level scaling enabled,**
[image]

Comment: What error do you get? Do you try that as you want?

Comment: @Charles Xu, Not yet, I have completed setting up the namespace with ResourceQuota enabled. I am bit worried now how the VM level scaling gonna happen when the namespace limits are defined.

Comment: I don't think the namespace will limit the nodes. The VM scale does it as usual, the namespace just limits the pods inside it, not the nodes.